# What do the -f and -m in gcc/clang compiler options stand for

Tags: gcc

**Summary**: What do the `-f` and `-m` in `gcc` and `clang` compiler options stand for?

**Details**:

When using `clang` I've noticed that many compiler options start with `-f` and others start with `-m`.  I assume that there is some historical reason for this and I was curious so I looked at the `gcc` help and saw the following:

> Options starting with -g, -f, -m, -O, -W, or --param are automatically
>   passed on to the various sub-processes invoked by gcc.  In order to
>   pass  other options on to these processes the -W options must
>   be used.

If I had to guess I think that `-f` might stand for frontend and `-m` for machine.  But I'd be interested to hear a more comprehensive answer, possibly including the other sub-processes that gcc invokes.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Comment: @Gabriel `-m` could stand for "microprocessor".

Comment: `-m` does not stand for "microprocessor".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to gcc onlinedocs, options of the form `-ffoo` and `-fno-foo` stand for **machine independent** code generation conventions.

Examples: `fpic`, `-fno-pic`

`-m` options stand for **machine dependent** options.

eg: `-mcpu`, `-march`, `-matomic`

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options or [https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/gnu/gcc_2.html#SEC43](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/cs1300/doc/gnu/gcc_2.html#SEC43)

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Submodel-Options.html#Submodel-Options or [https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/gnu/gcc_2.html#SEC16](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/cs1300/doc/gnu/gcc_2.html#SEC16)

Answer (score 24):

I don't have specific sources that state what **'f'** and **'m'** mean, but we can infer based on usage patterns found in documentation.

**'f'** stands for 'flag'.

Flags are on if specified via '`-fFLAG`' and off via '`-fno-FLAG`'

ex:

```
  -fpic         # flag to set position independent code 
  -fno-builtin  # don't recognize build in functions ...
```

The technical definition is that 'f' defines "Control the interface conventions used in code generation".

Src:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html
(e.g -fpci, when this **flag** is set)

**'m'** stands for mode. One general characteristic is that it sometimes has parameters. e.g

```
 -mabi=name   #abi mode = name
 -mcpu=cpu
```

Src:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Standard-Names.html  (e.g ... when this **mode**...)

Comment: sounds reasonable.  Do you get a badge for answering a 4-year-old unanswered question :)?

Comment: :-D. I took the time to answer this because yesterday I was looking for the same thing while reading GCC article on compiling shared libraries (with -fpci) and was wondering what the 'f' bit was.

Comment: To readers: Please note that this answer is completely incorrect. 'f' is for machine-independent settings, and 'm' is for machine-dependent settings. Counterexamples: "-mcrc/-mno-crc" is "flag-like", and "-fc++-abi" is "mode-like". The first setting described in the first link is "-fstack-reuse=reuse-level", which isn't a flag. The second source provided in the original post isn't even talking about the GCC frontend; it's describing naming conventions for the GCC internals' register-transfer-language code generation pass.