# what does the first m in -masm mean?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc

I'm new to gcc, just a question on `gcc -masm`, I know that by using masm we can elect the (dis-)assembly dialect from ATT(default), to Intel. And -masm is a GNU option and has nothing to do with Microsoft's Macro Assembler (masm).
But then what does the first m in `-masm` mean?

Comment: `-m` is for **M**achine option.

Comment: Correct; it's a coincident that GAS `.intel_syntax` uses MASM-like syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the -f and -m in gcc/clang compiler options stand for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227501/what-do-the-f-and-m-in-gcc-clang-compiler-options-stand-for)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gcc has [so many options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary) that there needs to be a way to break them up into groups, if programmers are to have any chance of remembering the ones they need.  This is done by using the first letter of the option to indicate the group it belongs to, and the rest to describe the specific option itself.

`-m` introduces a **m**achine option: something that is specific to gcc's behavior when compiling for a particular machine.  Your -masm= only makes sense for x86, since it selects between x86 assembly dialects.  There are many other x86-specific options (`-march=pentium` to generate code that runs best on a Pentium, `-mno-red-zone` to change the "red zone" calling convention, etc) and many more for other architectures (`-mthumb` on ARM to select a particular instruction mode it has).

Some other groups worth knowing about:

- `-W` for options to request **w**arnings about various possible problems in your code: `-Wuninitialized` to get warnings about uninitialized variables, for instance.

  (Exception: `-Wp, -Wa, -Wl` aren't for warnings, but are used to "pass through" options to the preprocessor / assembler / linker respectively.)
- `-f` to set **f**lags that affect the parsing, optimization and code generation process, in a somewhat machine-independent way: `-fstrength-reduce` to request a particular optimization called "strength reduction", `-fpic` for position-independent code, etc.
- `-O` for options that control the overall amount or priorities of **o**ptimization: `-O0` for none, `-O3` for lots, `-Os` to optimize for size, etc.
- `-g` for options controlling debu**g** information to be included in the generated object files.
- `-d` for options that are meant to be used by compiler **d**evelopers, that might dump information about the compilation process.

Comment: `-Wl` also happens to be used to pass options to the linker.

Comment: Thanks, this is super useful! Do you have a source that might list all of the options?  I am looking for what options `-D<option>` represent

Comment: @Cole: That's the link right at the top of my answer.  `-D` is under Preprocessor Options, as `-Dmacro[=defn]`.  It defines a macro.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry, I got confused with CMake `-DAN_OPTION_NAME` style flags.