# How to link to archive file (.a) library using clang?

Tags: clang, clang++

I have a program (lets call it test.cpp) that depends on a library (sample.a) that I need to link to in order to build the program. The library file is in another folder. Here is what I am currently putting in the command line to try and compile:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall test.cpp -o test -L/Users/cdw/common/lib/ -lsample.a
```

However, I keep getting an "ld: library not found for -lsample.a" error

Why does this happen? I know that "sample.a" is in

/Users/cdw/common/lib/

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-l` option automatically prepends `lib` to its argument, and searches for a file with that name plus `.a`, `.so`, etc.  I don't think this behavior can be changed.

Your options are:

1. Rename your library to `libsample.a`, and use `-lsample` on the command line (without `.a`).  This is the more conventional approach.

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall test.cpp -o test -L/Users/cdw/common/lib/ -lsample
```

2. Don't use `-L` or `-l`, and just give the full path to the library file.

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall test.cpp -o test /Users/cdw/common/lib/sample.a
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Where is the official documentation for the flags? Is there a way I can learn these practically? I feel like I searched all over the internet and could not find step by step examples where I know what these flags are doing lol.

Comment: @Corey4005: clang mostly uses the same command-line syntax as gcc, which is fully documented at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html.  The documentation of clang itself is at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#command-line-options but mostly just covers the differences from gcc.

Comment: @Corey4005: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62766235/what-does-the-first-m-in-masm-mean/62766430#62766430 where I mention a couple of the major option groups.