# when is 'f ' needed in gcc option

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

I'm new to gcc, sorry if my question sound weird.

It seems that 'f' prefix is needed for options such as:

```
linux> gcc -shared -fpic -o libvector.so addvec.c multvec.c
```

but why 'f' prefix is only for some option like `pic`, and for the `-share` option,  why not `-fshare`?

Comment: Not really an answer, but `-shared` is a linker option rather than a compiler option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227501

Comment: rather than nit-picking the spelling of the `gcc` options, suggest reading [gcc options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) and going with what the designers of that compiler implemented.